# How to add Firebase Remote Config for specific iOS app within firebase iOS project

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have an iOS Firebase project and I have 3 apps in it. They are pretty much the same apps besides the environment and of course bundle id.

I need this setup so the analytics and crash data is not mixed between environments.

I just started looking into Remote Config, and I do not see a way of using that feature on per app basis.

Is it possible? All I get now is an error on setup because the bundle IDs are not matching.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated